# How to find unallocated disk partition with parted or another tool?

Tags: fedora, filesystems, partition, disk, parted

I'm using Fedora server and I have an unused partition on `/dev/sda`. How can I find it with `parted` or another command? I can only list mounted and used partitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with parted you can see unallocated space if you use `print free` parted command, like `parted /dev/sda print free`.

Or issue `parted /dev/sda` command, and then inside parted type `print free`.

Example

```
# parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 2.1
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print free
Model: DELL PERC H710 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 3999GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
        17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB  Free Space
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   ext4                  boot
 2      211MB   4506MB  4295MB
 3      4506MB  8801MB  4295MB  linux-swap(v1)
 4      8801MB  3999GB  3990GB  ext4
        3999GB  3999GB  1032kB  Free Space
```